# 英語が残っている:「ヘルプ センター > バッジ」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 英語

「回答バッジ」で３個、「参加バッジ」で１個英語が残っています。

[image: 指摘用画像1]
[image: 指摘用画像2]

識者: Read the entire tour page

Answer (score 4):

jmacさんとyohjpさんの案を引き継いて、一案書かせていただきます。

```
 Explainer：説明者
 Refiner：論客
 Illuminator：啓蒙家
```

厳密に言えばRefinerに「論客」という意味はありませんが以下の観点から言葉を探しました。

- レベル的に「説明者」と「啓蒙化」の中間くらいの位置づけの肩書き。
- 元々の意味である「洗練させる人」「磨きあげる人」から大きく外れない言葉
- ポジティブな意味の言葉。（バッジをもらってうれしいように。）

参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

背景を説明します。

この3つのバッジが[すぐ最近](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator)に追加しました。ポイントは簡単に説明すると、改善余地のある質問を回答して、質問が削除になってしまうとその質問や回答は誰も助けることができない。回答を考える以上に、その回答への案内する質問の改善を考えるインセンティブを作成する為のバッジです。

だから、バッジ名は「ものの改善」テーマがあります（説明者、精油者、照明者）。

#### 適当案

Explainer：説明者
Refiner：解説者
Illuminator：[池上先生](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%A0%E4%B8%8A%E5%BD%B0)

12時間以内○○つの質問に対して、回答と編集を行う（回答0点以上）

Comment: 「池上先生」は面白いですね(笑)…とはいえ、あまり特定の時代背景/人物に強く紐付けるのも好ましくないと思います。"Illuminator"=「啓蒙家」という訳案はどうでしょう。"Refiner"＝「解説者」も悪くはないと思うのですが、説明～解説～啓蒙の並びで考えると、もう少し違う訳語が良い気もしますが思いつきませんでした。

Comment: 「12時間以内○○つの質問に対して、回答と編集を行う」では、12時間以内に○○件全ての回答＆編集を行うことと誤解されそうです。「スコア1以上の質問○○件に対して、12時間以内に回答と編集を行う。」ではどうでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

自伝作家も[かなりニューです](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit)。

過去にプロフィルのすべてのフィールドを更新しなかったら、バッジはもらえません。メールや本名を聞かれると違和感あるユーザーが多いし、当社の目的はデータ収集じゃないため、プロフィルの「自分について」だけにしました。

#### 適当案

プロフィルの「自分について」を更新しました。

> 識者: Read the entire tour page

ツアーを最後まで読む

Comment: "profile" の日本語は "プロフィール" のほうが適切です。原文の "Completed" を忠実に翻訳するのであれば、"完成させた" と表現するのがよいかもしれません。